# How to get the MAC-address from MSSQL server 2000

Tags: sql-server, mac-address, windows-server, windows-server-2000

I'm currently working on a project where I (among other things) need to find the MAC address for a remote computer. The problem is that i'm restriced to only accessing the computer throught SQL queries. (so I can't use WMI)

The remote computer is running Windows Server 2000, and Ms SQL server 2000.

I know the IP of the remote computer and I am able to log in with the admin account. How can I get the MAC address(preferably all of them) from the remote computer?

Thankful for answers.

Comment: NOTE: I am able to access the windows registry on the remote computer, throught SQL. Is there a static path to any key/value containing the MAC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it for my computer

//dont mind the makeQuery and querySrv

```
ResultTable res = makeQuery(querySrv,("USE Master; EXEC xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 'SOFTWARE\\Description\\Microsoft\\rpc\\UuidTemporaryData', 'NetworkAddress'"));
    byte[] bMac =(byte[])res.getRow(0).data[1];
    String mac = String.format("%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", bMac[0], bMac[1], bMac[2], bMac[3], bMac[4], bMac[5]);
```

This should work for other windows server 2000 servers

Thanks to @morgano for help with the formating and byte/hex converting

Answer (score 1):

I think that some kind of external call via `xp_cmdshell` is your only option. There is a likelihood that this feature may be disabled on your SQL Server (with good reason).

Something like

```
 Create table #results(data varchar(250))
 Insert #results
 exec master..xp_cmdshell 'ipconfig /all'

 select * from #results where data like 'physical address%'
```

Further to your comment - you may find it under in the registry under the

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
```

key, but if and where will be hardware configuration dependent.

Comment: Unfortunately xp_cmdshell is deactivated, so I can't do that

Comment: That's what i found at all tutorials, but it seems that for some reason  there is no "NetworkAddress"-key for any of the network adapters. And there are no other value looking anything like a MAC address.

Comment: @Darth_Peter Then it looks like you're stuck. You may have to adjust your requirements.

Comment: I'm afraid that you are right. I'll see if i might work around my restrictions or if I can solve it in another way

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/231405/retrieve-mac-address-of-sql-server), it doesn't seem you can. If you were using SQL Server 2005+, I'd think you could code up something in SQLCLR to do this without too much effort.